# Get Implementation of ServiceReference

Tags: osgi

I have a `ServiceReference` and I want to check if the implementation has an annotation. So I need to get the implementing class.

I figured out how to get the interfaces the service implements:

```
ServiceReference<T> reference = //
String[] interfaces = (String[]) reference.getProperty(org.osgi.framework.Constants.OBJECTCLASS);
```

But even with the JavaDoc I can't figure out how to get the implementation (obviously without getting the service from the context, because that might be a heavy-weight operation and I need just the class).

How do I get the implementation out of a `ServiceReference`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get the service object without getting the service object? I think you are asking for something impossible. You will need to get the service object to introspect it's implementation class for annotations. There is no other way. Make sure to unget the service object when done.

Comment: Bear in mind that even the OSGi Service Registry doesn't know the implementation class of the service object until the service is fetched from the registry. This is because the provider may instantiate the service object very late by registering a ServiceFactory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the service using `service = context.getService(reference)`. It is not a heavy weight operation.

You might also benefit from using a ServiceTracker.
Apart from that I am curious what you want to achieve.. maybe there is a better way.

Comment: It shouldn't be a heavy weight operation, but we're trying to create a small container that injects an `EntityManager` into our services, so I'm not sure if that's going to be true next week. That's why I'd love to not interfere with the lazy loading of the OSGi context just because I want to see if the service has an annotation marking it as "please inject into me".

Comment: There are already existing solutions for injecting an EntityManager. See Apache aries jpa examples https://github.com/apache/aries-jpa/tree/master/examples

Comment: Jep, we tried Aries and Gemini extensively, and both don't work with Hibernate. Since we only really need the `EntityManager` anyway we decided to do it ourself.

Comment: Aries JPA works very well with hibernate. The hibernate team even does their OSGi integration test with Aries JPA.